# Why no destructing in def form?

Tags: clojure, lisp, let, function, destructuring

In a `let` form (Clojure here) I can doing something like

```
(let [[u s v] (svd A)] 
   (do-something-with u v))
```

where `svd` returns a list of length three. This is a very natural sort of thing to do, so why isn't that we don't we have

```
(def [u s v] (svd A))
```

and its various generalizations as the default behavior of the `def` form? I don't see how this would interfere with anything that `def` is already doing. Can someone who understands the Zen of Lisp or Clojure explain why `def` does not support binding (with destructuring) as powerful as `let`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`def` is a special form at the compiler level: it makes a Var. `def` has to be available and usable before destructuring is available. You see something similar with `let*`, a compiler primitive that supports no destructuring: then after several thousand lines in `clojure/core.clj` the language is finally powerful enough to provide a version of `let` with destructuring, as a macro on top of `let*`.

If you want, you can write a macro (say, `def+`) that does this for you. Personally I think it's kinda gross and wouldn't use it, but using a Lisp means getting to use a language that suits you personally.

Comment: I think this is the sort of answer I was interested in. At risk of excessive editorialization on my part, I guess you are saying that the  reason this is not done in Clojure is partly technical (in that `def` happens to be a compiler primitive), and partly by convention (in that one (e.g. Rich Hickey) could have started with a primitive `def`* and declared `def` later at some point in the core).

Comment: @GabrielMitchell yes, that would have been possible. But it's a lot less useful for `def` than for `let`, and would lack symmetry. `let` **always** takes a vector and destructures inside of that; to make `def` do so would make it much less convenient, and to make def accept either a symbol or a destructuring form is pretty awful IMO.

Comment: Can you say a little more about why such a macro would be gross? Right now, I'm thinking that it's a great idea—but, based on your comment, I'm also wondering if it would somehow run against the grain of Clojure. Usually it's better to go with the grain of the language than rig up something that runs against it but seems appealing to someone inexperienced with the language. The fact that after 10 years, use of such a macro is not commonplace further makes me wonder if it's a clumsy solution to a problem best solved another way.

Comment: I think one reason is that `def`s are generally very simple objects whose properties are knowable at compile time. For example, functions, numbers, or keywords. For larger, more complicated objects, you usually shouldn't be computing them at compile time anyway. The macro is also a little bit tricky to write coherently, because `(destructure [[x [y]] (foo)])` includes gensymmed names for the temporary vectors as well as for `x` and `y`.

Comment: I wrote a def+ macro. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48998289/345427 I can see how it might be useful from the repl. As @amalloy said the gensyms are a problem. It there a way to detect that a let-var is a gensym?

Answer (score 3):

This is not perfect but it is start on writing a `def+`
https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/destructure

```
(defmacro def+
  "binding => binding-form
  internalizes binding-forms as if by def."
  {:added "1.9", :special-form true, :forms '[(def+ [bindings*])]}
  [& bindings]
  (let [bings (partition 2 (destructure bindings))]
    (sequence cat 
      ['(do) 
       (map (fn [[var value]] `(def ~var ~value)) bings)
       [(mapv (fn [[var _]] (str var)) bings)]])))
```

With that you can do...

```
(def+ [u s v] [1 5 9], foo "bar")
```

...while not compromising the simplicity of `def`...

```
(def+ foo "bar")
```

...which is what was requested and suggested.
This does still have the issue of introducing 
gensym variables into the global namespace.
The gensym problem could be handled but given 
the use case (use in repl) the additional variables
are probably acceptable.

Comment: I'm using this to help me `def` rows out of `let` bindings into my REPL, so I can then eval subforms of the let in isolation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`def` is basically the constructor for Vars. The first argument is the symbol that names the Var. It takes that symbol and returns a Var for that symbol. Destructuring would change these semantics.

You could write a macro that does it, though.

Comment: Isn't what you said equally true for `let`? I mean couldn't the same argument be made to say that `let` should not support destructuring bind?

Comment: Yes, sepp2k brings up the point that I am wondering about. So far as I understand, the basic difference between `def` and `let` is the scope of the bindings, and yet `let` seems to have a more general behavior. As Chuck points out, the fact that you could write a macro that is polymorphic in the first argument (one behavior for a single symbol, another behavior for lists of symbols) makes me wonder why this is not the default implementation.

Answer (score 2):

What follows are some philosophical justifications.

Clojure favors immutability over mutability, and all sources of mutability should be carefully considered and named. `def` creates mutable vars. Idiomatic Clojure therefore both doesn't use them much anyway, and also would not want it to be too easy to create many mutable vars without care (e.g. by destructuring). `let` and function argument destructuring, however, creates immutable bindings, so Clojure makes those bindings easy to create.

Vars created by `def` have global scope. Therefore you should name `def`ed vars carefully and keep them few in number. Destructuring `def` would make it too easy to create many `def`s without care. `let` and function argument destructuring, on the other hand, creates local, lexically-scoped bindings, so the convenience of destructuring does not cause name pollution.