# How can you destructure in the REPL?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, destructuring

Suppose I've got a function `(remove-bad-nodes g)` that returns a sequence like this:

```
[updated-g bad-nodes]
```

where `updated-g` is a graph with its bad nodes removed, and `bad-nodes` is a collection containing the removed nodes.

As an argument to a function or inside a `let`, I could destructure it like this:

```
(let [[g bads] (remove-bad-nodes g)]
  ...)
```

but that only defines local variables. How could I do that in the REPL, so that in future commands I can refer to the updated graph as `g` and the removed nodes as `bads`? The first thing that comes to mind is this:

```
(def [g bads] (remove-bad-nodes g)
```

but that doesn't work, because `def` needs its first argument to be a Symbol.

Note that I'm not asking why `def` doesn't have syntax like `let`; there's already [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8197329/1393162) about that. I'm wondering what is a convenient, practical way to work in the REPL with functions that return "multiple values". If there's some reason why in normal Clojure practice there's no need to destructure in the REPL, because you do something else instead, explaining that might make a useful answer. I've been running into this a lot lately, which is why I'm asking. Usually, but not always, these functions return an updated version of something along with some other information. In side-effecting code, the function would modify the object and return only one value (the removed nodes, in the example), but obviously that's not the Clojurely way to do it.

Comment: The answer to the linked question also answers yours: "If you want, you can write a macro (say, def+) that does this for you."

Comment: @amalloy Would you be willing to reopen this question? It's not super-important, since [your answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8198215/1393162) does give me a useful idea (write a `def+`  macro), but here's why I think this question should be answered separately: (1) It really is about something different: _how_ to destructure in the REPL. (2) The other answer tangentially mentions _a_ solution, not necessarily the only one. Maybe there's a whole other approach I should use—without a `def+` macro. I figure you probably have a good reason for calling the macro gross!

Comment: You've already got answers on this question too, showing you various things that you might call "destructuring at the REPL", mainly that in fact there is nothing special about the REPL at all, just a difference between how `let` and `def` behave. I don't see any reason to reopen this question as is, but of course you are free to edit it to improve its scope.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks for considering it. I just edited the question a bit, hopefully clarifying the problem as well as the wide possible scope of an answer. BTW, I'd be happy to post the macro here as an answer, just so it comes up when people google "clojure destructure repl". But I suspect that I'm missing some tidbit of wisdom that comes only from longer experience with Clojure, which might explain why people don't need such a macro.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to work with such functions in the repl is just to not `def` your intermediate results unless they are particularly interesting; for interesting-enough intermediate results it's not a big hassle to either `def` them to a single name, or to write multiple `def`s inside a destructuring form.

For example, instead of

```
(def [x y] (foo))
(def [a b] (bar x y))
```

you could write

```
(let [[x y] (foo),
      [x' y'] (bar x y)])
  (def a x') ; or maybe leave this out if `a` isn't that interesting
  (def b y'))
```

A nice side effect of this is that the code you write while playing around in the repl will look much more similar to the code you will one day add to your source file, where you will surely not be `def`ing things over and over, but rather destructuring them, passing them to functions, and so on. It will be easier to adapt the information you learned at the repl into a real program.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing unique about destructuring w/r/t the REPL. The answer to your question is essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197329/why-no-destructing-in-def-form). I think your options are:

`let`:

```
(let [[light burnt just-right] (classify-toasts (make-lots-of-toast))]
  (prn light burnt just-right))
```

`def` the individual values:

```
(def result (classify-toasts (make-lots-of-toast)))
(def light (nth result 0))
(def burnt (nth result 1))
(def just-right (nth result 2))
```

Or write a macro to do that `def` work for you.

You could also consider a different representation if your function is always returning a 3-tuple/vector e.g. you could alternatively return a map from `classify-toasts`:

```
{:light 1, :burnt 2, :just-right 3}
```

And then when you need one of those values, destructure the map using the keywords wherever you need:

```
(:light the-map) => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Observe:

```
user=> (def results [1 2 3])
#'user/results
user=> (let [[light burnt just-right] results] (def light light) (def burnt burnt) (def just-right just-right))
#'user/just-right
user=> light
1
user=> burnt
2
user=> just-right
3
```